# Jmeter Creating/Editing on .sh file linux

Tags: linux, api, shell, jmeter, response

can someone help me simulate this scenario, example I will create/update the **.sh** file. Tried to used "SSH Command Sampler" and used this command "vi testralph123.txt" but it doesn't work. SSH Command usually works if the Linux command is retrieve like "ls". Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Expected Result: upon invoking a sample it will generate/update .sh file.

Screenshot:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, `vi` command opens an editor in an interactive shell, it is not supported by the SSH Command sampler, I would recommend using something like [`echo`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) command instead with [stream redirection](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-lpic1-103-4/) into a file.

Example command would be:

```
echo "hello from JMeter" > testralph123.txt
```

It will create `testralph123.txt` file in your user's [home folder](https://www.javatpoint.com/linux-home-directory) or wherever you're getting when logging to the system via SSH.

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

Comment: The syntax you provided works. Thanks Dmitri,

is there's a way I can simulate this response

1st line -hello
2nd line -from
3rd line -Jmeter

Because the result I'm getting is one straight line
hello from JMeter